# Libre Office Base; Opens reports in read-only

Tags: report, readonly, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

LibreOffice Base opens reports automatically in read-only mode.
I've looked everywhere to find how to make sure it doesn't opens reports in read-only mode.

Does anyone knows how to make sure that LibreOffice Base won't open reports in read-only mode?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: More importantly, why does Libreoffice do this?  The data is opened in memory.  I shouldn't need a permanent place on disk to make in-memory edits.  Please fix this broken behavior @libreoffice_folks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a SAVE AS for your read-only report file. And then open the resulting .odt document. It will be editable.

Answer (score 1):

In the version I'm using (5.0.5) there's an info bar at the top of the created document:

> This document has been opened read-only.                                               <kbd>Edit Document</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/37966/read-only-content-cannot-be-changed-no-modifications-will-be-accepted/) by redN00ws, this worked for me:

Have you tried 'Format' > 'Sections' ? Then select the Section (eg. Section1) with 'Write Protection' activated and deactivate it. Now it should be editable.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I already have solved my problem a year ago.. Thanks anyways :)